# Django migration : deleted column, now django says it doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I want to get rid of a field of one of my models which has quite a few objects. This field was barely used so I removed every call to it from my code and did the migration. This migration couldn't be simpler, and it didn't cause any issue on my dev server. So I did the same on my running server.

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.19 on 2021-06-22 12:29

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0010_auto_20210611_0751'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='permission',
            name='type',
        ),
    ]
```

But when I try to access objects that relate to this model in my admin view, it throws

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column my_app_permission.type does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT "my_app_permission"."id", "my_app_permission"...

I don't understand why it looks for type when there is no reference to it in my code.

I ran Django's manage.py shell and requested my Permission objects. I got them without any issue. I tried to access their type field, but it didn't exist as expected since the migration. Which means in the database the column "type" has been deleted as I asked.

The error message doesn't give any insight as to what causes my error, here's the full traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column my_app_permission.type does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "my_app_permission"."id", "my_app_permission"...
                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1648, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1529, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1607, in _changeform_view
    media = media + inline_formset.media
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 324, in media
    media = self.opts.media + self.formset.media
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 394, in media
    if self.forms:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 136, in forms
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 112, in total_form_count
    initial_forms = self.initial_form_count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 913, in initial_form_count
    return super().initial_form_count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 574, in initial_form_count
    return len(self.get_queryset())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column my_app_permission.type does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "my_app_permission"."id", "my_app_permission"...
```

What am I missing ? Is there no way to remove a field from a model without ruining the application ?

**EDIT** : My problem has been resolved by restarting the container in which my django application was running. So it seems to me that it has something to do with cache. Digging deep into the framework,  I found the class *DatabaseCache* which uses the method cursor.execute with a query containing cache keys. Maybe this is what was happening, can't guarantee it though. I hope it helps someone.

(cf /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/db.py l 70)

Comment: Can you post the whole error message with full traceback?

Comment: I added the full traceback

Comment: Do you have any custom middleware or context processors? They might be still referring to the `.type` field.

Comment: I don't know what a context processor is, but I don't use any custom middleware, so none of the middlewares I use depend on my models

Comment: @PleaseHelp it seems the problem might be in your `admin.py` file, please show it's content.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat my admin.py file is over 1k lines long, what should I be looking for ?

Comment: Look for the model admin of the `permission` model, or if it is an inline there too. Likely you have some code that uses the `type` field or something.

Comment: I use the model in a TabularInline, and I didn't overload its ModelAdmin.

Comment: the TabularInline is basic, it only defines the "model" and "extra" fields.

Comment: the is no mention of "type" anywhere in the full traceback

Comment: Can you share your form?

Comment: which form do you think could be related to the problem ?

Comment: I did not override any form related to the Permission model.